# Converting StringType to TimestampType in Spark 3.0

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have been using pyspark 3.0. I have a dataframe with a column 'time' in StringType. I am trying to convert this to timestamp. The dataframe looks like this.

```
+---------------+
|           time|
+---------------+
|10:59:46.000 AM|
| 6:26:36.000 PM|
|11:13:38.000 PM|
+---------------+
```

I tried both to_timestamp() and unix_timestamp.

```
df.withColumn("new_time", F.to_timestamp(col("time"),"hh:mm:ss.SSS a")).show()
```

.

```
df.withColumn('new_time', F.unix_timestamp(inputDF['time'], 'hh:mm:ss.SSS a').cast(TimestampType())).show()
```

The error I'm getting is this.

```
org.apache.spark.SparkUpgradeException: You may get a different result due to the upgrading of Spark 3.0: Fail to parse &#39;6:26:36.000 PM&#39; in the new parser. You can set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy to LEGACY to restore the behavior before Spark 3.0, or set to CORRECTED and treat it as an invalid datetime string.
```

I want to know how it's done in Spark 3.0 without setting

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy","LEGACY")
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this-

```scala
df.withColumn("new_time", F.to_timestamp(F.lpad(col("time"), 15, "0"),"hh:mm:ss.SSS a")).show()
```

**`some Explanation`**

**`1. lpad(column, length, "<string_to_be_padded>")-`**

This function checks the `length` of the string specified and will left pad with the `string_to_be_padded` if length of string < length specified.

**`Example`**

the input row `6:26:36.000 PM` has only 14 chars and since the length specified is `15` it will left pad `0` (3rd argument) to make it of length 15. Now the o/p od lpad is `06:26:36.000 PM`. this matches our format specified in `to_timestamp`

More explanation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#lpad)

Comment: This works too. Could you give me a brief explanation of how this works? Thanks!

Comment: Added the minimal explanation

Answer (score 3):

No need for padding..

You need to change the format of conversion string.. Delete on "h" from that and it works then.

```
df.withColumn('new_time', f.unix_timestamp(df['Timestamp'], 'h:mm:ss.SSS a'))
```

explanation on the format:

```
'hh:mm:ss.SSS a'
01:00:00.000 pm
11:00:00.000 am

'h:mm:ss.SSS a'
1:00:00.000 pm
11:00:00.000 am
```

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you! I still wonder why there's one 'h' instead of 'hh' since there are 2 digits in the hour format.

Comment: Hi, It is just one digit incase there is one thus just single "h".